# class cast exception on orientation change (Android)

Tags: android

I have an activity which is hosted by tab activity. When i change screen orientation my app crashes.

```
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3791)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1596)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9977)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2346)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:778)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2332)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:9955)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:939)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.TabActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(TabActivity.java:84)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:911)
02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1132)
   02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):  at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
  02-14 21:01:35.825: E/AndroidRuntime(9424):   ... 12 more
```

This line in manifest doesn't help:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

And one thing else: in my activity i use custom view (horizontal ListView) from https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android

The app is working fine without this custom view, but i need to use it.

Comment: Please post your portrait and landscape layouts that are generating this crash.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to post images.(

Comment: The first tab contains listview 

Second tab contains HorizontalListView wich extends AdapterView<ListAdapter>

I found that if i remove listview from first tab or HorizontalListView from the second, i can change orientation without any problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to post images.

XML files are not images, and layouts are XML files.

> I found that if i remove listview from first tab or HorizontalListView from the second, i can change orientation without any problem

That, plus your symptoms, suggests that you named those two widgets with the same `android:id` value. That will not work, as their saved states are not the same. Either make them be both the same class, or name them something different.

Comment: >XML files are not images, and layouts are XML files.
@CommonsWare I hought that you want screenshots from me.
But you are right! They had the same id

Comment: @CommonsWare:I am facing same issue.I got the cause but how can we avoid this issue if we have included some .xml more than one time in layout?As I have inflated same .xml file in layout many times.

Answer (score 0):

Heed to what CommonsWare is saying, he's a mind reader :)

---

I'm just leave this here for archival.

Going by this:

android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState

1. Check your imports to see if you're using the right classes
2. do an instanceof check before conversion
3. paste the java code