# App crashes after rotate if I add options menu

Tags: android

I created app from "Empty Activity" template in Android Studio 1.4 and added options menu.

Resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_foo"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/word_foo"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/word_bar"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_baz"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="@string/word_baz"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

After change the orientation app crashes. What is wrong?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
```

I readed the answer here [class cast exception on orientation change (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880819/class-cast-exception-on-orientation-change-android) 
and I think it is not my case: I have absolutely empty layout. There is no widgets with id at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [class cast exception on orientation change (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880819/class-cast-exception-on-orientation-change-android)

Comment: your error has to do nothing with you menu so post the code with toolbar

Comment: @helldawg13 I have no code with toolbar: https://github.com/tseglevskiy/RotationExperiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jollydroid/rotateexperiment/MainActivity.java https://github.com/tseglevskiy/RotationExperiment/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Comment: @Nikola Why do you think it is my case? I have absolutely empty layout, without any widgets.

Comment: @helldawg13 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: @helldawg13 I've fount the error. the problem was in id of menu item. look at the answer for details

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I'm not native English speaker, and I forgot, that `bar` from sequence `foo`, `bar`, `baz` also has common value. And after menu item with id `action_foo` I created `action_bar`. It conflicts with some id in SDK layouts, as I presume, corresponded to ActionBar.

So solution is change id in `android:id="@+id/action_bar"` to something else.